# unity i need to run the update from infinite loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, unity-game-engine, infinite-loop

i try to change code from vb.net to unity.
the code in vb.net is using infinite loop inside functions ,and i update the form drawing by code application.doevents(),without any errors.

but in unity the window is not responding,only what i need if there is altenative to application.doevents(),if not so how to update from infinite loop inside function the frame.

here is example code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class ttt : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool runn = true;


    private void Start()
    {
    Start:

        if (runn == true)
        {
            f1();   
            var t = 9;
            var hh = t;
        }
        if (runn == true)
        {
            goto Start;
        }
    }

    void  f1()
    {
        var t = 9;
        var hh = t;
        f2();
        var tt = 9;
        var hhh = t;
    }

    void  f2()
    {
        //here i need to wait and run update one frame.(or to run the update function ,and to unfreze the program.)
        var t = 9;
        var hh = t;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var t = 9;
        var hh = t;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternetive of application.doevents is coroutines. And you cant use a loop like that in unity. Because of the loop that you have in start function, program will never start. Because its not ending. And in unity, update function is always working after initialization over.(More info about execution order:[https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html])

If we examine the example code again:

```
bool runn = true;
bool runupdate=false;
private void Start()
{
    //Start:

    if (runn)
    {
        f1(); //will call f1()  
        var t = 9; //since we have that in f1 already we dont need it in here
        var hh = t;
    }
    /*if (runn == true)
    {
        goto Start; // this makes unity stuck in never ending loop so program will never start 
    }               // because of here */
}
void  f1()
{
    var t = 9; //And again we have that code in f2 already
    var hh = t;
    f2();
    var tt = 9;
    var hhh = t; //you want to start the update function in f2 which makes here unnecessary
}
void  f2()
{
    //here i need to wait and run update one frame.(or to run the update function ,and to unfreze the program.)
    //you can make it like that
    runupdate=true;//this starts the update function
    var t = 9; //and since update will work always, here is also unnecessary
    var hh = t;
}
void Update()
{
    if(runupdate)      //this is the loop of unity you can call functions when update works
    {
        var t = 9;
        var hh = t;
    }
}
```

So the last version of your example code would be just that:

```
void Update()
{
    var t = 9;
    var hh = t;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ,but this is not the main code,this only sample of code for the main issue. the main code is consist of more than 500 function and methods and when i entered the code it will never out ,only in vb.net i update the form by application.doevents() its working good.the main code is for atari vcs 2600 emulator .it read code and after that looping thraw code ,and every frame counter increased ,it draw it form.